# XML File Has Numeric Data For String Data Type

Tags: xml

I have a somewhat comfortable level when it comes to programming languages.  But I see this and am mindblown.  It is set as `string` but numeric values.

How do you have a `string` with numeric data input, and how do you decipher this?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
  <string name="datasent">[-93, -114, -35, -103, -32, 82, 4, -41, 54, -79, 31, 61, 75, 86, -78, -6]</string>
</map>
```

Edited information

I obviously did a poor job explaining the situation prior.  We had a developer, who up and quit.  An application was developed that would send data from systemA to systemB and the only files that explain how this exchange occurs is 25 `XML` files.

No idea what language was used or anything as there are only `XML` files

Comment: "45" I'm a wizard.  I decypher it with my wand.  How do you want to decypher it?

Comment: That is why I asked.  I was not sure if there was already logic that explained how to decipher that I was unaware of.  This place is full of amazing developers/programmers/coders and if that exists I would love to learn.

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh - to my knowledge there is no way to decipher that w/o having the cipher or the key that is used to encrypt that string.  Simply looking at what you have provided we have no way to tell you what any of it means unfortunately.

Comment: 1) Maybe the "datasent" *could* be string data. 2) In what environment do you want to parse the data?

Comment: How you decypher it depends entirely on what you're doing and with what tools.  But strings can always contain numbers, and if you want numbers back out again, you have to parse the string.  That looks like valid json.  Here, try this--type ctrl-shift-j, and paste the following into the console: `JSON.parse("[-93, -144]")[0]` Notice you get the first number from the array out.  Again, I reiterate, I'm a wizard.

Comment: @user2676140 but I am a smart butt.  And a wizard, as I have previously stated twice.  It's up to OP to ask a question we can answer.  He has not yet done so.  Luckily, there's an [edit] button where he can improve his question by telling us what he is trying to do, using what languages or tools, and why he can't accomplish his goal.  A bit about what he has tried will prevent him from wasting other's time, which is always a courtesy.

Comment: @Will Ctrl-shift-j doesn't work in all browsers.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm a wizard.  It will work in his.  You people, I swear.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - I know how to parse data from a string.  These numeric values are associated with text as text is what is being passed.  Maybe this is a hashkey or some random number assignment given by the writer.  I just was not sure if there was any methodology of deciphering.

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh You are going to have to examine the programs which send and receive the data. Just hope that the now-absent programmer commented their code, if it is not obvious.